# Why I am getting SonarQube runner executable was not found for SonarQubeRunner 5.3?

Tags: jenkins, sonarqube

I am trying to integrate jenkins and sonarqube.

Sonarqube version is 5.3.

I have a java gradle project to monitor.  I have installed both jenkins and sonar on my local linux system. Both run individually fine.

I have setup

Below is my entire configuration.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The SonarQubeRunner 5.3 does not exist.

You incorrectly configured `SONAR_RUNNER_PATH`. You set path to the SonarQube server instead of the runner. The latest version is 2.5.1 (see [releases](https://github.com/SonarSource/sonar-runner/releases)).

Better choose option `Install automatically` (at work I use SonarQube Runner 2.4 with SonarQube Server 5.3 without any problems).